# Requests encoding settings fail

Tags: python, python-requests

I have python code

```
from requests import get
for x in xrange(0, 200, 50):
    url = "http://pornolab.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=1765&start={}".format(x)
    print "Get '{}'".format(url)
    r = get(url)
    print "Encoding: {}".format(r.encoding)
```

The problem is that i have Encoding: windows-1251  and sometimes Encoding: ISO-8859-1  on the same title.  Here the result

First start

```
Get http://pornolab.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=1765&start=50 
Encoding: windows-1251
```

Second start

```
Get http://pornolab.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=1765&start=50
Encoding: ISO-8859-1
```

Why this happens? How to setup encoding settings in requests?

Comment: maybe it is a sign you need to cut down on your porn watching ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Requests Documentation](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#response-content) -

> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers. The text encoding guessed by Requests is used when you access r.text. You can find out what encoding Requests is using, and change it, using the r.encoding property:
>
> `r.encoding`
>
> `'utf-8'`
>
> `r.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'`
>
> If you change the encoding, Requests will use the new value of r.encoding whenever you call r.text. You might want to do this in any situation where you can apply special logic to work out what the encoding of the content will be. For example, HTTP and XML have the ability to specify their encoding in their body. In situations like this, you should use r.content to find the encoding, and then set r.encoding. This will let you use r.text with the correct encoding.

Comment: No problem, I am glad it helped :)